In a nested multicols environment, how to only set the most inner one has separation ruler?
My question is a dual to This one. In a pair of nested multicols environments, I want the inner one to have separation rules, i.e. the "checks" in the following mwe:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2} 
Test Test   Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test

\begin{multicols}{2}\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
Check Check Check Check Check Check Check Check 
\end{multicols} 
Test Test   Test Test   Test Test Test Test Test Test 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}

I tried to dualize the above post and remove the outside \setlength, as the above code. But then no separation ruler appears at all.

Just as in the earlier posting to which you provided a link to, the instruction \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt} has to be run before the multicols environment it is supposed to affect.
To limit the scope of \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt} to the "inner" instance, I suggest placing this instruction and the inner multicols environment in a separate TeX group, via \begingroup and \endgroup directives.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol} % for 'multicols' environment

\begin{document}
\raggedright % just for this example

\begin{multicols}{2} 
Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1

\begingroup
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Checka Checka Checka Checka 
Checkb Checkb Checkb Checkb 
\end{multicols} 
\endgroup

Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2
\end{multicols}

\end{document}


I'd define a suitable environment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{rmulticols}[2][0.4pt]{%
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{#1}\begin{multicols}{#2}%
}{\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2} 
\lipsum[1][1-2]

\begin{rmulticols}{2}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{rmulticols} 
\lipsum[3]
\end{multicols}

Or the other way around

\begin{rmulticols}{2} 
\lipsum[1][1-2]

\begin{rmulticols}[0pt]{2}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{rmulticols} 
\lipsum[3]
\end{rmulticols}

\end{document}


